# how to listen to key press in all apps?

Tags: blackberry, key

Can we create an app in blackberry which listens to key presses for all blackberry applications? I have implemented KeyListener in one of my classes. But its only working for Key presses in my app. It doesn't work for key presses in other apps. Would appreciate any help. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Because key events are consuming by those applications and are not valid as they are consumed.

Your application won't receive any event that is already consumed by someone else.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your reply. Then can we edit the other application's key events and add our code to them. Or, can we extend the keyListeners and add our customised code to them?

Comment: If you have access to source code of these apps, then you can change their keylisteners and avoid event consuming. But it may lead to unexpected behaviour inside of those applications. Because other parts of those apps may expect that some event is consumed. For instance - when you open a list and display a screen. If you do not consume "open list item" event, then it will be passed to opened screen and will produce unexpected behaviour, depending on the first focused object. If it is a button, then it may be pressed, and so on.